# Intelligently name an object on AWS S3 when creating the object with Rails Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I am building an app with Ruby on Rails in the backend, and I would like to intelligently name the files I upload via the app to S3 (perhaps via the Ruby object's UUID).

Is there a way to specify how you would like an S3 object to be named through Active Storage?  If not, are there any alternatives to S3 that have this capability?

I want to name S3 objects this way so that I can pull them straight from the frontend in certain situations without having to grab their URLs from the backend.  Thank you for any help (I'm fairly new to this).

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what do you mean by _intelligently_?

Comment: For sure!  It seems like now files uploaded to S3 via Rails are assigned a name at random.  Is there a way to specify what I would like those files to be saved as?  As in, is there a way to ensure that a file is saved as "HotDog1234.jpg" in my S3 bucket?  I am pretty sure I can rename things manually after the initial save, but what I want to do is initially deliberately choose a name.